# Unraveling a nested IF statement to make it more user friendly

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to streamline a nested IF statement that my lab uses on a spreadsheet for keeping track of what we make every day for testing - it's a ridiculously complex statement that reads the value of a cell in column A, compares that value to one of the nested IFs and whether the value in a cell of the same row in column P is within the specified range, then returns "Yes" if the two statements evaluate as true and "No" if not.

This output is then used as part of a conditional formatting formula that will turn the cell red if the value of the nested IF is "No" and green if the value of the nested IF is "Yes".  The formula in question is as follows (and for the record, I didn't write it, I just inherited it):

=IF(Sheet1!A5="","",IF(OR(Sheet1!A5="Potato Dextrose Agar",Sheet1!A5="Sabouraud Dextrose Agar",Sheet1!A5="Vegan PDA"),IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=5.4,Sheet1!P5<=5.8),"Yes","No"),IF(OR(Sheet1!A5="EE Broth",Sheet1!A5="R2A Medium",Sheet1!A5="Slanetz & Bartley Medium",Sheet1!A5="Yeast Extract Agar",Sheet1!A5="Cetrimide Agar",Sheet1!A5="Harlequin Medium",Sheet1!A5="Nutrient TSB",Sheet1!A5="Vegitone + Tween",Sheet1!A5="Vegitone LB Broth"),IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=7,Sheet1!P5<=7.4),"Yes","No"),IF(OR(Sheet1!A5="MRD",Sheet1!A5="Neutraliser 3",Sheet1!A5="Neutraliser 4",Sheet1!A5="Neutraliser 5",Sheet1!A5="TNC",Sheet1!A5="Minimal Agar",Sheet1!A5="Minimal Broth",Sheet1!A5="Neutraliser 9",Sheet1!A5="Vegan TNC"),IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=6.8,Sheet1!P5<=7.2),"Yes","No"),IF(OR(Sheet1!A5="Neutraliser 1",Sheet1!A5="Neutraliser 2",Sheet1!A5="Pseudomonous Agar"),IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=6.9,Sheet1!P5<=7.3),"Yes","No"),IF(OR(Sheet1!A5="Candida Chromogenic Agar",Sheet1!A5="Neutraliser 7"),IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=5.8,Sheet1!P5<=6.2),"Yes","No"),IF(Sheet1!A5="Malt Extract Agar",IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=5.2,Sheet1!P5<=5.6),"Yes","No"),IF(Sheet1!A5="Buffered Charcoal Yeast Extract Agar",IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=6.8,Sheet1!P5<=7),"Yes","No"),IF(Sheet1!A5="CLED Bevis Modification",IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=7.3,Sheet1!P5<=7.7),"Yes","No"),IF(Sheet1!A5="DE Neutralising Broth",IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=7.4,Sheet1!P5<=7.8),"Yes","No"),IF(Sheet1!A5="RVS Broth",IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=5,Sheet1!P5<=5.4),"Yes","No"),IF(Sheet1!A5="Sabouraud Liquid Medium",IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=5.5,Sheet1!P5<=5.9),"Yes","No"),IF(OR(Sheet1!A5="Reinforced Clostridial Medium",Sheet1!A5="Tryptone Water"),IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=6.6,Sheet1!P5<=7),"Yes","No"),IF(OR(Sheet1!A5="MacConkey Agar",Sheet1!A5="Mannitol Salt Agar",Sheet1!A5="VRBGA",Sheet1!A5="Blood Agar",Sheet1!A5="XLD Agar"),IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=7.2,Sheet1!P5<=7.6),"Yes","No"),IF(OR(Sheet1!A5="MacConkey Broth",Sheet1!A5="Microbial Content Test Agar",Sheet1!A5="Tryptone Soy Agar",Sheet1!A5="Tryptone Soy Broth",Sheet1!A5="PBS",Sheet1!A5="Mueller Hinton Agar",Sheet1!A5="Vegan Tryptone Soy Agar"),IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=7.1,Sheet1!P5<=7.5),"Yes","No"),IF(Sheet1!A5="Middlebrook 7H11 Agar Base",IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=6.4,Sheet1!P5<=6.8),"Yes","No"),IF(Sheet1!A5="Neutraliser 8",IF(AND(Sheet1!P5>=6,Sheet1!P5<=6.4),"Yes","No"),"Another Neutraliser")))))))))))))))))

If there is a way to streamline the above using any other function, especially if it makes it easier to edit the statement to remove data errors (the numbers are pH values and at least one range is not correct), I would welcome the help to implement it - my Excel skills are a little rusty.

Thanks in advance, :D

Comment: It seems very complicated, however a sample data with expected output shown using **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** then forum members can easily provide a far better solution, also using multiple nested `IFs` is not recommended or suggested by any, which dont need explanations as well as we already can see. To make it more flexible and streamline one would use some reference or tables and then use a `VLOOKUP()` or `XLOOKUP()` or may be some other ways to resolve. Please post some sample data

Comment: Also more over with the advent of newer functions in `Modern Excel` aka `MS365` there gives a plenty of ways to make this short. May be i am exaggerating more but i feel there is a shorter way to do it. Please post some sample data

Comment: Are you sure there is no error in this formula?
All pH intervals have a width of 0.4, and only in one case of "Buffered Charcoal Yeast Extract Agar" is 0.2 (from 6.8 to 7). If all the intervals were of equal length, the formula would be slightly shorter.

Answer (score 3):

If you put your list of neutralisers with pH ranges somewhere in your workbook and give it a name `List` (name refers to data without header 48 rows x 3 columns), you can use the formula:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A5="","",IFERROR(IF(MEDIAN(Sheet1!P5,VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A5,List,{2,3},FALSE))=Sheet1!P5,"Yes","No"),"Another Neutraliser"))
```

Your `List` read from the given formula:

| Neutraliser | pH min | pH max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Potato Dextrose Agar | 5.4 | 5.8 |
| Sabouraud Dextrose Agar | 5.4 | 5.8 |
| Vegan PDA | 5.4 | 5.8 |
| EE Broth | 7 | 7.4 |
| R2A Medium | 7 | 7.4 |
| Slanetz & Bartley Medium | 7 | 7.4 |
| Yeast Extract Agar | 7 | 7.4 |
| Cetrimide Agar | 7 | 7.4 |
| Harlequin Medium | 7 | 7.4 |
| Nutrient TSB | 7 | 7.4 |
| Vegitone + Tween | 7 | 7.4 |
| Vegitone LB Broth | 7 | 7.4 |
| MRD | 6.8 | 7.2 |
| Neutraliser 3 | 6.8 | 7.2 |
| Neutraliser 4 | 6.8 | 7.2 |
| Neutraliser 5 | 6.8 | 7.2 |
| TNC | 6.8 | 7.2 |
| Minimal Agar | 6.8 | 7.2 |
| Minimal Broth | 6.8 | 7.2 |
| Neutraliser 9 | 6.8 | 7.2 |
| Vegan TNC | 6.8 | 7.2 |
| Neutraliser 1 | 6.9 | 7.3 |
| Neutraliser 2 | 6.9 | 7.3 |
| Pseudomonous Agar | 6.9 | 7.3 |
| Candida Chromogenic Agar | 5.8 | 6.2 |
| Neutraliser 7 | 5.8 | 6.2 |
| Malt Extract Agar | 5.2 | 5.6 |
| Buffered Charcoal Yeast Extract Agar | 6.8 | 7 |
| CLED Bevis Modification | 7.3 | 7.7 |
| DE Neutralising Broth | 7.4 | 7.8 |
| RVS Broth | 5 | 5.4 |
| Sabouraud Liquid Medium | 5.5 | 5.9 |
| Reinforced Clostridial Medium | 6.6 | 7 |
| Tryptone Water | 6.6 | 7 |
| MacConkey Agar | 7.2 | 7.6 |
| Mannitol Salt Agar | 7.2 | 7.6 |
| VRBGA | 7.2 | 7.6 |
| Blood Agar | 7.2 | 7.6 |
| XLD Agar | 7.2 | 7.6 |
| MacConkey Broth | 7.1 | 7.5 |
| Microbial Content Test Agar | 7.1 | 7.5 |
| Tryptone Soy Agar | 7.1 | 7.5 |
| Tryptone Soy Broth | 7.1 | 7.5 |
| PBS | 7.1 | 7.5 |
| Mueller Hinton Agar | 7.1 | 7.5 |
| Vegan Tryptone Soy Agar | 7.1 | 7.5 |
| Middlebrook 7H11 Agar Base | 6.4 | 6.8 |
| Neutraliser 8 | 6 | 6.4 |

The screenshot:
[image: pH_List]

Comment: I've set up the table as above with the formula you suggested, but each cell with the new formula in it is returning 'No', even if there is data in the associated cell (example: I have the value 'Tryptone Soy Agar' in cell A5, with the measured pH value of 7.34 in cell P5.  This value is obviously within the required range so should have the formula return the value 'Yes' which is then fed to the conditional formatting rule to turn the cell green.  The formula is returning 'No', however, which then feeds into the conditional formatting rule to turn the cell red.

Comment: It's hard for me to determine the cause without seeing the workbook. I showed the screen of my sheet. Use the `Evaluate Formula` tool to see at what point the result becomes incorrect.

Comment: The workbook is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fDj74QTK9iKkIJ7LGbrD8v9eSN2LNpRy/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=110551603768402027949&rtpof=true&sd=true.

Comment: This was an older version of a spreadsheet without dynamic formulas, so the formula had to be completed with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I really appreciate your help on this :D